# How to eliminate the error "list index out of range"

Tags: python

I was working on the problem below:

> Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.
>
> If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

Example 1:

> Input: ["flower","flow","flight"]
> Output: "fl"
> Example 2:
>
> Input: ["dog","racecar","car"]
> Output: ""
> Explanation: There is no common prefix among the input strings.

But the results showed that on line 6 (code `a1= strs[0]`) there was an error "List index out of range" here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        if not strs:
            return ""
        a1= strs[0] 
        a2=strs[1]
        if a1[0]!= a2[0]:
            return ""
        elif len(strs)==2:
            new=strs[0]
            new_x=strs[1]
            xmin=min(len(strs[0]),len(strs[1]))
            for i in range(xmin):
                i=0
                if new[i]==new_x[i]:
                    i+=1
                else:
                    res=i
                    rescom=new[:res]
                    return rescom
        else:
                    j=1
                    while j<len(strs):
                        strs_new=strs[j]
                        strs_cmp=strs[j-1]
                        for k in range(0,(min(len(strs_new)-1,len(strs_cmp)-1))):
                            if strs_new[k]==strs_cmp[k]:
                                k+=1  
                            else:
                                res=k
                        j+=1
                    return strs_new[:res]
```

Comment: Please post the code and the problem directly into your question - it makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. As Nick mentioned, you need to put your code and other details in the question. See [ask] and [mre] for more details.

Comment: Please show the code where you call the function. Also, why is this inside a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I could not replicate your error with your pasted code.</s> However, I think what you actually want to obtain, is something like this:

```
def longestCommonPrefix(strs):
    if not strs: return ""
    smallest = min([len(x) for x in strs])
    prefix = ""
    for i in range(smallest):
        a = strs[0][i]
        if all([x[i] == a for x in strs]):
            prefix += a
        else: break
    return prefix
```

Edit: After looking at your code once more, yours can't handle the case of `strs = [""]`, or any other similar single-item list, because you call `a2=strs[1]` before you've checked that the length of `strs` is at least `2`.